# Big Sur: preview slow to open pdfs

Tags: preview

I have a 2017 MBP, and after updating to Big Sur, I find that it's extremely slow in opening pdfs in Preview. Has anyone else noticed this, and if so, is there a way to make it faster? Did rendering settings somehow change from their previous defaults on the old operating systems, making it slower now?

Comment: I haven't noticed anything. Is this any PDFs, or particularly large ones, or image-based ones or vector/text ones...? Have you tested opening PDFs in a new user account, or when booting in Safe Boot mode?

Comment: Have you set that apps should reopen with the previously opened files?

Comment: @lhf: I just restarted, and I noticed that after I successfully opened a pdf (which first took a while), it was faster the next time. Does this sound like what youre referring to?

Comment: @rrrrr, no, not really. But if it's working for you now, good!

Comment: @benwiggy: I'll try rebooting in safemode tonight and testing that, thanks for the suggestion